# snakemake input function strange results

Tags: snakemake

I have this rules. I try to use case vs control.

```
CASE1,CONTROL1
CASE2,CONTROL2
CASE3,CONTROL3

rule macs2:
    input:   get_files
    output: "ALIGN/result/macs2/{case}_vs_{control}/",
            "ALIGN/result/macs2/{case}_vs_{control}/{case}_peaks.xls",
            "ALIGN/result/macs2/{case}_vs_{control}/{case}_summits.bed"
    log: "log/{case}_vs_{control}.macs2"
    threads: 2
    conda:
        "envs/macs.yaml"
    message: "macs2 comparison"
    params:
        size="hs",
        name="{case}"
    shell:
          """
             macs2 callpeak -t {input[0]} -c {input[1]} -f BAM -g hs -n {params.name}  --nomodel -B -q 0.01 --outdir {output[0]} -m 3 50 -g {params.size} --extsize 147 2>{log}
          """
```

So this is the function:

```
def get_files(wildcards):
   case = wildcards.case
   control = aCondition[case][0]
   return ["ALIGN/result/{}_filter_dup.bam".format(case), "ALIGN/result/{}_filter_dup.bam".format(control)]
```

If I have this rule all. I have all the comparison of one sample with all inputs.

```
expand("ALIGN/result/macs2/{case}_vs_{control}/",case=CASE,control=CONTROL),
```

Example:

```
CASE1,CONTROL2
CASE1,CONTROL3
CASE1,CONTROL1
...
```

I expect to have only

```
CASE1,CONTROL1
CASE2,CONTROL2
CASE3,CONTROL3
```

In general: How can write the rule all where I use input function on rule?

Comment: Where and how do you define `CASE` and `CONTROL`? Have you read the example using `zip` at the end of this section of the documentation: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking. Did you try making a rule that asks for the outputfiles you are interested in?

```
rule all:
    input: 
        expand(
            "ALIGN/result/macs2/{case}_vs_{control}/{case}_peaks.xls",
            case=["case1", "case2", "case3"],
            control=["control1", "control2", "control3"]
        )
```